# No match password_hash and password_verify after retrieving from database

Tags: php, mysqli

After studying six issues on SO regarding the subject above, I am still not able to match a password, inserted into table with `password_hash` and retrieved/validated by `password_verify`.

If I'm checking the password with the password functions in a plain file, without interaction with mysqli, encrypting and decrypting works very fine.

The password field in my table is VARCHAR(255). This is following the suggestions made in earlier questions.

The way I use password_hash function:

```
public function fSetEncPass( $password ){

                    $pw = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT );
                    return $pw;

}//end f
```

I also tried `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`

And this is the way I try to retrieve the password:

```
$sql = sprintf( 'select password from table where email ="%s"', mysqli_real_escape_string( $myConnect::$cn, $email ) );
                        $result = mysqli_query( $myConnect::$cn, $sql );
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_row( $result );
                        if ( password_verify( $password, $row[0] ) ) {

                                return TRUE;

                        }else{
                                //var_dump(password_verify( $password, $row[0] ));
                                return FALSE;

                        }//end if
```

$row[0] contains the hash that was created using `password_hash`.

I ensured to store the user input in variables with single quotes. I understood from earlier questions that catching user input in double quotes could cause variable expansion.

Furthermore I noticed, that echoing $row[0] exactly corresponds to the value stored in my table. 
My conclusion is that password_verify should have returned `TRUE` instead of `FALSE`. But it is not...

`var_dump(password_verify( $password, $row[0] ));` shows:`bool(false)`

I increased verbosity level on error_reporting to dispay all errors:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Unfortunately no errors are displayed.

I suppose I am doing things wrong, but what exactly?

Comment: Whats var_dump($password, $row[0]) gives you?

Comment: How are you inserting the row?

Comment: Start by looking at the difference between what `fSetEncPass` says the password _should_ be, and what the returned value from MySQL is - that's what the comparison function actually compares in the end. Also, if it works when you've tried it by itself in a separate file, compare the differences in the hash from that file to what you have in the database and what you're comparing against.

Comment: var_dump shows: bool(false)

Comment: Insert the password: $sql = sprintf( "insert into table ( password)
                        VALUES ( '%s' )",
                        mysqli_real_escape_string ( $myConnect::$cn, $password),                  
                  );
                        $result=mysqli_query( $myConnect::$cn, $sql );

                        if ( mysqli_affected_rows( $myConnect::$cn ) > 0 ){
                                       return TRUE;
                                }//end if

                        }else{
                                return FALSE;
                        }//end if

Comment: As a side note: learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) instead of that sprintf BS.

Comment: @MatsLindh: I followed your suggestion to check the value from the database and the value that was generated by password_hash. In bothe cases exactly the same value: $2y$10$p0dquWKIYI1M/U49j1DiC.OLmxjO/VjvSgrwwBsggEwkOTHoAjDeG. Were created from the password 'Walvispee122%%'